Extract option missing from Files (Nautilus) after upgrade/conversion to AlmaLinux
I recently upgraded and converted my server from Centos 7 to AlmaLinux 8 via leapp, and after upgrading, I noticed that in the default Gnome3 file manager (nautilus), under Centos 7 I could right lick on a RAR file and choose "Extract" (or maybe it was "Extract here") to extract the contents of the archive, and if there were multiple files in the root of the archive, it would create a folder using the archives name and extract the files to that. In AlmaLinux, I don't have that option anymore. I can open archives with fileroller by double-clicking on them, but I have to manually extract them, and if I want to extract them to a directory I have to manually create that also. Is there a way to get that functionality back in Nautilus?
